# Roadmap to learning Hinduism?

Tags: ramayana, dharma

I am a Hindu, however, I do not feel as though I understand my religion. I pray, go to the temple, follow religious rules, etc., but I don't understand *why* I do it. It feels very un-genuine that I am "practicing" Hinduism, even if I don't understand it. So, I want to try to learn.

I have some knowledge, but it's very general (like a very vague plot of Ramayana). In fact, I don't even know the names of many of the Gods. What I am looking for is a roadmap for understanding Hinduism better, from the beginning. I am not looking for one with extreme details (for example, I likely will not be able to memorize read the whole Gita), but I would like to have a good understanding (kind of like a jack of all trades) of **dharma** and **Ramayana**.

I know what I'm asking may be a little vague, but it's because even I don't know what I don't know, and what I want to ask. I'm simply looking to get a fresh start to learning the religion, and any help that people can give is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: @F16F Welcome to Hinduism SE, Please go through the posts Sarvabhouma added in his comment above. You'll get an idea.

Comment: @F16F If you know Tamil read the book Arthamulla Indhu Madham by Kannadasan consisting 10 volumes costing INR400.